# I have purchased a domain, what else do i need?

Tags: web-server, web-hosting, website

I have purchased the domain name.

To host my app (yet in development mode though), is it enough if i buy some web-space or do i need to buy an IP-ADDRESS.

Answer (score 4):

If you have someone to host your domain on their web server, no, you don't need an IP address. Otherwise you'll need to contact your service provider and ask for a business connection and dedicated static IP if you plan to set up, configure, and administer your own web server on which to host your domain name.